# Split string at space and return first element in C++

Tags: c++, string, split

How do I split string at space and return first element? For example, in Python you would do:

```
string = 'hello how are you today'
ret = string.split(' ')[0]
print(ret)
'hello'
```

Doing this in C++, I would imagine that I would need to split the string first. Looking at this online, I have seen several long methods, but what would be the best one that works like the code above? An example for a C++ split that I found is

```
#include <boost/regex.hpp>
#include <boost/algorithm/string/regex.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
using namespace boost;

void print( vector <string> & v )
{
  for (size_t n = 0; n < v.size(); n++)
    cout << "\"" << v[ n ] << "\"\n";
  cout << endl;
}

int main()
{
  string s = "one->two->thirty-four";
  vector <string> fields;

  split_regex( fields, s, regex( "->" ) );
  print( fields );

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you come across [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/236129/splitting-a-string-in-c?rq=1)? I can't really tell how this is any different.

Comment: oh and getting the split to return as a list is optimal. from what i have seen this c++ code returns it like "one"
"two"
"thirty-four"

Comment: probably run that through something like a for loop though.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Why bother with splitting the whole string and making copies of every token along the way since you will throw them in the end (because you only need the first token)?

In your very specific case, just use [`std::string::find()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find):

```
std::string s = "one two three";
auto first_token = s.substr(0, s.find(' '));
```

Note that if no space character is found, your token will be the whole string.

(and, of course, in C++03 replace `auto` with the appropriate type name, ie. `std::string`)

Comment: It returns an index. You can do `auto first_token = s.substr(0, s.find(' '));`

Comment: @chris Oh my, I guess I got confused with some other `find` algorithm in the Standard library. My bad.

Comment: Yes, `std::find` returns an iterator.

Comment: forbids the declaration of it/first_token with no type

Comment: nevermind did not see the "replace auto with appropriate type"